# State management for a list of items - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have 2 components. We'll call them `parent component` and `child component`. So in the parent component i'm mapping a group of objects as follows.

```
<ScrollView style={[styles.container]}>

                    {userFriendsList.length > 0
                    && userFriendsList.map(reviewer => (

                        <Child reviewer={reviewer} key={reviewer.id}
                                        addToArray={this.addToArray.bind(this)}
                                        removeFromArray={this.removeFromArray.bind(this)}/>
                    ))}

</ScrollView>
```

Following is my child component

```
class Child extends Component {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {

            added: false

        }

    }

    //Send data to parent component
    handleSendingData(reviewer) {

        this.setState({
            added: !this.state.added
        }, () => {
            if (this.state.added === true) {
                this.props.addToArray(data)
            } else {

                this.props.removeFromArray(data.reviewerId)

            }
        });

        const data = {
            reviewerId: reviewer.id,
            reviewerName: reviewer.name,
            reviewerImage: reviewer.url
        };


    }


    render() {

        const {reviewer} = this.props;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addtogroupcard} onPress={() => this.handleSendingData(reviewer)}>
                <Image source={{uri: `${imageEnv}${reviewer.url}`}} style={styles.friendimg}/>
                <Text style={styles.friendname}>{reviewer.name}</Text>
                {this.state.added ? <Icon name="ios-checkmark-outline" style={styles.friendaddicon}/> :
                    <Icon name="ios-add-circle-outline" style={styles.friendaddicon}/>
                }

            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }

}
```

As you can see i'm doing state changes in my child component to display different icons according to the state.

```
{this.state.added ? <Icon name="ios-checkmark-outline" style={styles.friendaddicon}/> :
                    <Icon name="ios-add-circle-outline" style={styles.friendaddicon}/>
}
```

How can i do this state change from my parent component? Is using redux the correct approach here?

Comment: did your problem get solved if yes accept the answer which solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Redux will help you in easily managing the whole state of your application but you can also do what you require here using react also. If you want to call the function which sets the state which is in your child component from your parent component also. This can be done using `ref's` in react. Here is an example:

```
//Parent component
import React from 'react';
import Child from './child.js';

class Parent extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return (
    <div onClick={this.child.func();}>
        <Child ref={instance => { this.child = instance; }}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

Child component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Child extends React.Component {
    func = () => {
       console.log('child');
     // here you can set state;
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
               child component
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Child;
```

Comment: how is changePlayer function connected to parent component?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the best way to handle state management in a child/parent relationship like this is to have the parent store the state. Whatever state objects the children need access to should be passed down as props. If a child needs to change the state then pass a function to the child from the parent as a prop.